# Need help skipping an empty json array with VBA

Tags: arrays, json, vba, parsing

I am looping through different process ids to access the data within the json and copy it to my spreadsheet. However, some of the process id contain no data and every time my code gets to these empty arrays I get an error.  I have tried different variations of if statements to skip this but still get an error.  The empty array is at "expectedRateSetList"

I have tried different variations of if statements to skip this but still get an error.  I've tried 'If J is null, if J is nothing, If J is empty" etc but I still can't get it to work. I've also tried "On error go to" but this hasn't worked.

``````````````
    `````````````
    For l = 2 To last_row(tb, 2)

    Set J = setJSON(url)
    Set J = CallByName(J, "expectedRateSetList", VbGet)  <---This is the array that is empty        
    If J Is Null Then GoTo next_log
    On Error GoTo next_log
    Set J = CallByName(J, "0", VbGet)   
    Set J = CallByName(J, "expectedRateList", VbGet)
    next_log:
    Next l
``````````````

```
'json array looks like this:
{"processId":X,"expectedRateSetList":[],"warehouseId":"warehouseX"}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* `J` is an array? `Set` assigns object references, not arrays, and `CallByName` works with an object instance, not an array - that said `0` is an illegal member name, so that `"0"` call is guaranteed to fail. What does `setJSON` actually do/return? What is the specific error you're getting exactly?

Comment: Are you using VBA-Tools/JSON? Then `J` would be a `Dictionary` object, and `J("expectedRateSetList")` should get you another `Dictionary`; objects are never `Null` in VB, but they can be `Nothing` - that said you shouldn't be changing the type and meaning of `J` like this. Variables are cheap - declare them with an explicit data type, and give them meaningful names!

Comment: Assuming `J` (well the first one anyway) is a `Dictionary`, then `If J.Count > 0 Then` should rid you of that `GoTo` jump.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Is correct. I wonder sometimes if this confusion about array comes from the fact the JSON itself has object {} ( unordered set of name/value pairs) and array [] (ordered collection of values)  - http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf   These terms are not applied in the same way in VBA implementations where {} is dict and [] is collection.

Answer (score 1):

`J` is definitely not an array. `J` is an object, likely a `Dictionary`. You can check if a dictionary contains any items by querying its `Count` property - that removes the need for the line label and `GoTo` jump, at the cost of increased nesting (but then, the loop body should probably be refactored into its own procedure anyway):

```
    If J.Count > 0 Then
        ' there are items
    End If
Next
```

Note that `CallByName(J, "MemberName", vbGet)` can be replaced by late-bound `J.MemberName` calls - but then again assuming your parsing isn't hand-crafted and you *are* getting nested dictionaries, that would be `J("MemberName")`; the property you're actually invoking is the (default) `Items` property: `J.Items("MemberName")` is equivalent.

Comment: This makes sense.  I will definitely try this.  Right now they put me on a couple different projects so it may be a bit before I try this.

Comment: You can use the *locals* toolwindow to inspect the object structure. Good luck!